# CS50P - Problem Set 2 - Problem 1 (camelCase): Did I overthink this?

Tags: python, cs50

This was the first problem and it took me a few hours to figure out an answer. The task to is implement a program that prompts the user for the name of a variable in camel case and outputs the corresponding name in snake case. It took me less than 3 minutes to come up with this, which satisfied any input where only one capital existed:

```
camelcase = input("camelCase: ")
for letter in camelcase:
    if letter.isupper():
        first, second, last = camelcase.partition(letter)
        second = "_" + second.lower()
print("snakecase: ", first + second + last)
```

However to come up with the following to satisfy inputs with multiple capitals I spent a solid 2-3 hours:

```
camelcase = input("camelCase: ")
for letter in camelcase:
    if letter.isupper():
        _ = camelcase.split(letter)
        _.insert(1, "_" + letter.lower())
        camelcase = "".join(_)
print("snake_case:", camelcase)
```

I feel like given that this was the first problem, there is a simpler solution that I completely overlooked. Any advice? Please remember that my knowledge scope is only as far as lecture 3 which introduced loops.

I first tried adding a second if letter.isupper() loop to the final variable resulting from the .partition operation, however, that wasn't working as intended.
Then I tried using the s.insert() method on the original input but learnt through the documentation that strings are immutable.
Eventually after reading and experimenting with a plethora of different str functions and their results I managed to get to my submission.

Comment: Before you write any code, try to explain your solution to yourself using sentences or bullet points. Now you have a pseudocode reference of the algorithm to convert into Python. When you run into a problem with your approach, like strings being immutable, go back and fix your pseudocode so that your solution makes sense and try again. With practice you'll be doing most of this in your head but it helps to write it out when you're just getting started in programming.

Comment: A simpler solution is to use another variable to hold the result. Loop over the characters in the input, concatenating them to the result variable. When the current character is uppercase, concatenate `_` and `letter.lower()` to the result instead.

Comment: @Woodford thank you for the insight, I told myself I would do this after Lecture 1 when David mentioned pseudocode comments, I even wrote it down in my notes, but I forgot. I used this technique to solve problem 3 in the set immediately, thank you :)

Comment: @Barmar fml that is so obvious I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you so much, I used this to solve problem 3 where we had to remove vowels.